# Does the row locking on slave database also apply to master database?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

In a transaction, for example,

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT count(*) as count FROM `order` WHERE user_id = 25286 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
INSERT INTO `order` (`id`, `user_id`, `product_id`) VALUES (NULL, '25286', '36296');
```

we perform the `SELECT LOCK IN SHARE MODE;` the `SELECT` query will be executed on the slave database and lock a row.

Does the `SELECT LOCK IN SHARE MODE` also create a row locking on the master database so that the INSERT query will not run on a master database?

Comment: No it does not. I have had a similar requirement but other way around.

Comment: Could I know how you handled it?

Comment: There is no direct way. What we decided was to route all these specific queries to Master server only. So that no matter which session connects, it will always do it on Master only

Comment: Thank you Madhur. Look like that's the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

**NO** - Locking does not permeate across the Server(s). So basically, an explicit Lock on the Slave server, does not lock the corresponding table(s) in the Master server, and *vice versa*.

A simple workaround, which we used in our case, was to direct all these specific locking queries to **Master Server only**. So that no matter whichever client session is running, these queries are always running at Master Server only. Thus concurrent connections issues are handled.

I have done a similar sort of filtering in PHP code. For directing queries to relevant servers (Read queries to Slave, and Write Queries to Master), a custom function is written to identify the **type** of query.

One noteworthy point is that, queries within a Transaction/Lock/Unlock operation, are always considered **Write** queries.

Also, for `Set`, only `SET AUTOCOMMIT` and `SET TRANSACTION` are Write commands.

Please find below a largely toned down version of the actual code we are using:

```
/*
* All the WRITE operation commands
*/
$write_commands = array(
    'create', 
    'alter', 
    'drop', 
    'truncate',
    'comment', 
    'rename', 
    'insert', 
    'update',
    'delete', 
    'merge', 
    'call', 
    'lock', 
    'unlock',
    'start', 
    'commit', 
    'rollback', 
    'savepoint',
    'set', 
    'replace' 
);


/*
* method to determine whether Read or Write
* @param $sql String (SQL query string)
* @return: void
*/
function determineReadOrWrite(string $sql): void {

    $dml_query = false;

    $words = str_word_count(strtolower(trim($sql)), 1);
    $first_word = isset($words[0]) ? $words[0] : '';
    $second_word = isset($words[1]) ? $words[1] : '';

    if (in_array($first_word, $this->write_commands)) {
        /* if it is not "set" then we set to master link */
        if ($first_word !== 'set'
        || ($first_word === 'set' && $second_word === 'autocommit')
        || ($first_word === 'set' && $second_word === 'transaction')
        ) {
            $dml_query = true;

            /* If we Lock tables or Begin a Transaction, we should run on Write servers only */
            /* till we Commit/Rollback or Unlock Tables */
            if(($first_word === 'start' && $second_word === 'transaction') 
            || $first_word === 'lock'){

                /* Set whether the current query is starting a Transaction / Lock etc */
                $this->wait_for_commit_rollback = true;
            }

            /* We are doing Commit/Rollback or Unlock Tables */
            if ($first_word === 'commit' 
            || $first_word === 'rollback' 
            || $first_word === 'unlock') {
                $this->wait_for_commit_rollback = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /* It's a insert/update/delete/etc query - to be run on Write Db only */
    if ($dml_query || $this->wait_for_commit_rollback) { 
        $this->setActiveConnectionToWrite(true);            

    } else {
        $this->setActiveConnectionToRead();
    }

}
```